# character counter for webform textarea drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am relatively new to drupal. I have webform module and webform validation module installed. I was able to limit the number of characters in webform textarea using webform validation. However, this module does not support character counter for the fields. I have looked at this solution http://drupal.org/node/1459650#comment-5699952 which using maxlength module, but it is very unclear.

I am planning to write a module implement `hook_webform_component_info_alter(&$components)` to add jquery or javascript on to the webform textarea field. Is this a correct way. If so or If not how would i do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: This question is addressed here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90047/how-to-actually-set-a-maxlength-for-textarea-field-in-contact-form

Answer (score 0):

**Maxlength module** (http://drupal.org/project/maxlength) is the best solution to solve your problem. You don't need webform validation module for it.

Basically after enabling maxlength module, you just need to edit webform textarea field and specify the max length in "Maxlength JS" field. For example, I have tested it by specifying the max length to 140 and it shows me the number of characters remaining when I start tying in the textarea. You can also customize the message which will be displayed under textarea by modifying "Count down message" field there.

I have tested this and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi, I have tried but the Maxlength JS field only appear on drupal CCK Field (or Textarea) but not in the webform field. So if you go Structure -> Content Types -> Webform -> Manage Field and add a new textarea, then it is fine(you can see Maxlength JS because these are drupal CCK fields). However if you go to Content -> Add Content -> Webform. And start create new webform with fields here. The Maxlength JS is not available.